# String Split in C

Tags: c

I want to split a String in C.

My String is defined by my Struct:

```
struct String
{   
    char *c;   
    int length;             
    int maxLength;      
}
```

Then I have a function that does the splitting. Perhaps C has something that does this, but although I wanted my own, I have not found anything that will do it so far.

```
String ** spliter(String *s)
{
   if(s == NULL)
     return NULL;

   // set of splitters: {'\n', ' '}

}
```

Input looks something like this: `This is Sparta.`
Then I want to return a pointer to each character array.

```
*p1 = This
*p2 = is
*p3 = Sparta.
```

If that makes any sense, I want an array of pointers, and each pointer points to a character array.

I will have to realloc the String as I increment the size of each character array. Probably my biggest problem is imagining how the pointers work.

Similar problem: [c splitting a char* into an char**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291468/c-splitting-a-char-into-an-char/4291534#4291534)

So, how do I go about doing this?

Comment: I am a bit afraid of strtok, since it will destroy the original string fed into it.

Comment: Use `strdup` to make a copy of it?

Comment: Anyone have the .c source code for strtok?

Comment: [Here's](https://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/invisible/src/crt/strtok.c.htm) an example.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `strtok`, check out `man 3 strtok`, or [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strtok.html) if you're not on *nix.

You would use it like this: (Assuming that you can write the `add_string` code yourself.)

```
String ** spliter(String *s)
{
   if(s == NULL)
     return NULL;

    String **return_strings = NULL;
    char *delim = " \n";
    char *string = strtok(s, delim);
    int i = 0;


    for(i = 0; add_string(return_strings, string, i) != -1; i++) {
        string = strtok(NULL, delim);
    }

    return strings;
}
```

Note that if you need to save the original string (`strtok` modifies the string it works on), you'll need to call `strdup` on the original string, then operate on the copy.

EDIT: OP said he was having trouble thinking about the pointers. With the above code sample, `add_string` only has to worry about dealing with a string of characters, as opposed to an array of pointers to pointers to characters. So it might look something like this:

```
int add_string(String **strings, char *s, int len)
{
    if(s == NULL)
        return -1;

    String *current_string = NULL;
    strings = realloc(strings, sizeof(String) * (len + 1));
    current_string = strings[len];

    /* fill out struct fields here */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    string test = "aa aa bbc cccd";
    vector<string> strvec;
    string strtemp;

    string::size_type pos1, pos2;
    pos2 = test.find(' ');
    pos1 = 0;        
    while (string::npos != pos2)
    {
            strvec.push_back(test.substr(pos1, pos2 - pos1));

            pos1 = pos2 + 1;
            pos2 = test.find(' ', pos1);
    }
    strvec.push_back(test.substr(pos1));

    vector<string>::iterator iter1 = strvec.begin(), iter2 = strvec.end();
    while (iter1 != iter2)
    {
            cout << *iter1 << endl;
            ++iter1;
    } 

    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a exemple :

```
String ** spliter(String *s)                                                                                                                                                                                        
{
  int  i;
  int j;
  char *p1;
  char *p2;
  char *p3;

  i = 0;
  j = 0;
  if(s == NULL)
    return NULL;
  p1 = malloc(sizeof(*p1) * strlen(s));
  p2 = malloc(sizeof(*p2) * strlen(s));
  p3 = malloc(sizeof(*p3) * strlen(s));
  while (s[i] != ' ')
    {
      p1[j++] = s[i];
      i++;
    }
  i++;
  j = 0;
  while (s[i] != ' ')
    {
      p2[j++] = s[i];
      i++;
    }
  i++;
  j = 0;
  while (s[i] != '\0')
    {
      p3[j++] = s[i];
      i++;
    }
  printf("%s\n", p1);
  printf("%s\n", p2);
  printf("%s\n", p3);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at strtok? It should be possible to do this using strtok.

Answer (score 0):

add strdup and strtok can work on a copy of the string.  The split() call is more generic than the other spliter() examples, but does the same thing with strtok on a duplicate.

```
char **
split(char **result, char *w, const char *src, const char *delim)
{
    int i=0;
    char *p;
    strcpy(w,src);
    for(p=strtok(w, delim) ; p!=NULL; p=strtok('\0', delim) )
    {
        result[i++]=p;
        result[i]=NULL;
    }
    return result;
}

void display(String *p)
{
   char *result[24]={NULL};
   char *w=strdup(p->c);
   char **s=split(result, w, p->, "\t \n");  split on \n \t and space as delimiters
   for( ; *s!=NULL; s++)
      printf("%s\n", *s);
   free(w);
}
```